# Good-fences sub folder use

Tags: javascript, package, structure

I'm using [Good-Fences](https://www.npmjs.com/package/good-fences) to differentiate my folders and creating package-like folders. currently, for each package I've added the file (fence.json):

```
{
    "tags": [],
    "exports": [
        "./Contracts/**"
    ]
}
```

Which means - each folder can export files only from Contracts subfolder (= each folder can only import files in other Contracts sub-folder and not the folder itself).

To my question: in each folder, I also have Test sub-folder. I want my fence.json to enable the files inside Test to import any file in the other folders (including those that are not in Contracts). Any suggestion on how to create the new fence.json file?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is using another fence file inside Test.
So package/fense.json:

```
{
    "tags": [],
    "exports": [
        "./Contracts/**",
        {
            "modules": "./**",
            "accessibleTo": ["test-folders"]
        }
    ]
}
```

and package/Test/fense.json:

```
{
    "tags": ["test-folders"],
    "exports": []
}
```